# Add styled-components to Codepen

Tags: styled-components, codepen

Try to use styled-components in my pen https://codepen.io/mxshrv/pen/aMXvQd, but get error

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined

styled is not defined
```

How to add a library correctly for my pen?

Comment: you can use stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making `const styled = window.styled` like in this Pen here:
https://codepen.io/beauhaus/pen/OaRwbm

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Styled Components v5 has added a new requirement. [You now also need `react-is`](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#what-do-i-need-to-do-to-migrate-to-v5) to be able to use SC.

So in your pen, under external scripts, search for `react-is` and add it.

I would also recommend moving it up to be just after `react` and `react-dom` and before your `styled-components` script.